# How to change the text colour of a spinner

Tags: java, android, xml, android-spinner

As a noob I find the other answers for this question hard to understand. I initialize a spinner like so:

```
mMembership = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.RegisterMembershipSpinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> member_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                    R.array.membership_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
            member_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            // Apply the adapter to the spinner
            mMembership.setAdapter(member_adapter);
```

And I have created and XML called spinner_items.xml in the layout folder with the following content:

```
     <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:id="@+id/textSpinner"
        />
```

What should I do from here in order to allow me to change the text color of the spinner items?

Comment: post a screenshot too

Comment: Your `spinner_items` file has your `textColor` attribute, change the `#FFFFFF` to something else. That's black so if your background is black you won't see it. Also don't hard code your color values use the `colors.xml` file to define your colors and call it by using `@color/your_defined_color`

Comment: #FFFFFF is white. Still got the same error

Comment: Sorry my mistake, meant to write white. You're not using your `spinner_items.xml` file in your code. You're using the android specified one.  Does your `XML` file only contain your `TextView` or is it in some sort of layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` with `R.layout.spinner_items`

and add `android:id="@android:id/text1"` to your XML file

EDIT:
If you want to change spinner selected item text color.

```
Spinner mMembership = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.RegisterMembershipSpinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> member_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.membership_array, R.layout.spinner_items);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    member_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    mMembership.setAdapter(member_adapter);
```

and content of `spinner_items.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
/>
```

OR if you want to change spinner dropdown item text color, then your java code is:

```
mMembership = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.RegisterMembershipSpinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> member_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.membership_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    member_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_items);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    mMembership.setAdapter(member_adapter);
```

and `spinner_items.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="#00FF00"/>
```

Comment: No luck. That gave me the error: E/ArrayAdapter: You must supply a resource ID for a TextView

Comment: In xml filed try to change id of TextView to android:id="@android:id/text1"

Comment: edited answer. If you still getting error, please provide your full log